# Approximating a function by Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

The introduction to Taylor polynomial and remainder is given in various calculus texts with different flavors. Still, I wanted to know one more thing by comparing two things about it.

For this, consider non-constant, non-polynomial function, which is infinitely many times differentiable in an open interval $I$.

Fix $a\in I$.

Let $P(x)=f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \cdots + \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$ be the $k$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ around $a$.

(1) If we fix degree of polynomial and approach to $a$ (i.e. if we take $x$ close to $a$) then the error between $f(x)$ and $P(x)$ goes to $0$ much faster compared to $(x-a)^{k+1}$.

This will give a polynomial approximation for $f(x)$ of degree $k$ **in suitably small interval around $a$**.

(2) Fix domain of interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, and vary the degree of the polynomial $P(x)$; **we get better and better approximation to to $f(x)$ in the domain $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.**

**Question:** Practically, it may depend on the function $f$, whether to come close to $a$, or take large degree of Taylor polynomial for approximation of function $f(x)$ by a polynomial. Can one illustrate me by some example(s) where one situation is better than the other?

Comment: Your statements about "better and better" approximations are not entirely accurate. You do know that there are infinitely differentiable functions $f(x)$ all of whose Taylor polynomials about $0$ are identically zero, don't you? So for these the error at $x$ is always $f(x)$.

Comment: Actually, regarding your first point, the error between $f(x)$ and $P(x)$ usually goes to zero at pretty much exactly the same rate as $(x-a)^{k+1}$ as $x \to a$. Regarding your second point, this one is quite a bit more subtle and has to do with the fact that in the Taylor remainder, although $\frac{\delta^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ definitely goes to zero, the factor $f^{(k+1)}(\xi)$ can sometimes blow up, possibly quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most practical situations, the two points go hand in hand. For an interval of choice you typically determine the degree to fix and work with that. On the other hand, if estimating higher order derivatives is not possible or practical then you fix an interval within which the contribution from higher order derivatives can be ignored because the  possible error is within a specified budget.

A practical example of this from Options pricing. If you don't know what an option is think of it is a financial instrument whose price ($f$) is given as a function of a underlying asset's price ($s$), that asset's volatility ($\sigma$), time to maturity of the option ($t$), some type of risk free interest rate ($r$), and many other variables depending upon the type of option (including some properties of the option which may remain fixed). This function may not have a closed form expression in many cases.

If you want to make a quick estimation of an option's price in response to a small change in the underlying stock's price ($s$) you can use the delta-gamma approximation. This is nothing but the Taylor's approximation up to second order with:

$$
\delta = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{s}} \quad , \quad \gamma = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial s^2}
$$

These approximations are only valid in a small interval because the derivatives themselves change with changes in $s$.

If you are short on computing resources, you may want to use the delta-gamma approximation while the asset's price has not deviated materially from the point at which you last calculated your deltas, gammas, and the original prices. If you are outside that range you can then calculate the derivatives and the prices using a full (expensive) revaluation. The trade off between accuracy and computing power will be driven by your tolerance for discrepancies.